# Can't initialize GoogleMap, returns null

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to initialize a GoogleMap instance, but SupportMapFragment returns null.
Here is my MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{
GoogleMap gMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initMap();                            //here is the NullPointerExeption
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
}


public boolean initMap()
{

    if (gMap == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragMap);
        gMap = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
    return (gMap != null);
}
```

}

And this is my activity_map.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragMap"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

what is the problem? if I comment out the initMap() function, it works fine and displays the map.

Comment: Tried calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_map)` before `initMap()`? The view isn't initialized before you try to retrieve the map

Comment: tanx man! it solved my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change the order like

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);     
initMap();
```

First you should  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);`  and then reference **Map** from `SupportMapFragment`.